# Event of DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling, datagridviewcombobox

I am using the following code for binding a combo box column in a grid view in my winform

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgBatch = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)grvProduct.Rows[pRowIndex].Cells[pComboColName];
                DataTable dtBatch = new DataTable();
                dtBatch = iExportSalesOrder.SelectProductDetails(pack_detl_ID);
                dgBatch.DataSource = dtBatch;
                dgBatch.ValueMember = "qty";
                dgBatch.DisplayMember = "sBatch_No";
```

How can i get the `selectedindexchange` event of this combo box column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the  DataGridView.EditingControlShowing event and casting the EventArgs to   a ComboBox control and then you can use the SelectesIndexChanged event.